# ジャイロモジュール MPU-6050で角速度を取得したいがうまくいかない

Tags: c, arduino

使っているマイコンはArduino　nanoです。サンプリング周期を決めて単純に積分しているのですが、どうにもうまくいきません。複雑なプログラムに見えますが、大事なのはここだけです。

```
rx= (float)((data[8] <<8 ) | data[9])/GYRO_CONV ;
  ry= (float)((data[10] <<8 ) | data[11])/GYRO_CONV;
  rz= (float)((data[12] <<8 ) | data[13])/GYRO_CONV;

  ang_x += rx*Ts;
  ang_y += ry*Ts;
  ang_z += rz*Ts;


  delay(100);
```

そして生じている問題は以下です。
まずスケッチ全体を実行すると、ang＿xがひたすらに負に増えていきます。なぜならrxが何もしていないのに-1.48~-1.63をウロウロしているからです。故障かなと思い、rxに1.5を足して実行してみますが今度はang_xが90度で2.0や-8.0などいろいろな値を取ります。

コードに間違いがあるのでしょうか

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define ACC_CONV 1671.8 //acceleration converter
#define GYRO_CONV 131.1 //deg/s converter


volatile uint8_t data[14]; //to accomodate data


const float Ts=0.1; //[s]
volatile float ang_x=0; // ang x data
volatile float ang_y=0; // ang y data
volatile float ang_z=0; //ang z data





volatile float rx=0; //gyro x data
volatile float ry=0; //gyro y data
volatile float rz=0; //gyro z data



//reg_setter
void i2cWriteReg(uint8_t ad, uint8_t reg, volatile uint8_t data ){

  Wire.beginTransmission(ad); //starts transmission
  Wire.write(reg); //select reg
  Wire.write(data); //write data
  Wire.endTransmission(); //ends transmission

}



void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600); //Starts serial
  Wire.begin(); //Starts I2C

  i2cWriteReg(0x68,0x6b,0x00); //Turn on a sensor
  i2cWriteReg(0x68,0x1b,0x00); //-250 < deg/s <250
  i2cWriteReg(0x68,0x1c,0x00); // -2g < acc <2g
  
}

void loop() {

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68); //Starts transmission
  Wire.write(0x3b); //select data top
  Wire.endTransmission(); //ends transmission
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,14); //get data from top to 14byte

  uint8_t i =0;

  while (Wire.available())
  {
    data[i++]=Wire.read(); //accomodate data
  }


  rx= (float)((data[8] <<8 ) | data[9])/GYRO_CONV ;
  ry= (float)((data[10] <<8 ) | data[11])/GYRO_CONV;
  rz= (float)((data[12] <<8 ) | data[13])/GYRO_CONV;
  
  ang_x += rx*Ts;
  ang_y += ry*Ts;
  ang_z += rz*Ts;

 

  OUTPUT_SERIAL();
  delay(100);





}


void OUTPUT_SERIAL(){

  Serial.print("ang_x: ");
  Serial.print(ang_x);
  Serial.print("\tang_y: ");
  Serial.print(ang_y);
  Serial.print("\tang_z: ");
  Serial.print(ang_z);

  Serial.print("\trx: ");
  Serial.print(rx);
  Serial.print("\try: ");
  Serial.print(ry);
  Serial.print("\trz: ");
  Serial.println(rz);
}
```

Comment: 角速度は定数で割っただけの値のようですが。[Arduinoを用いて6軸加速度センサを使う](https://novicengineering.com/arduino%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A66%E8%BB%B8%E5%8A%A0%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B5%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86/), [【Arduino】MPU6050とI2C通信して、加速度とジャイロのデータを取得](https://shizenkarasuzon.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/02/16/162647) そこから導かれる角度とかですか？ [MPU6050を用いて角度（yaw角）を算出したい](https://teratail.com/questions/181247), [6軸ジャイロセンサMPU6050をArduinoで使って角度を取得](https://sgrsn1711.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/03/11/004401)

Comment: 導いたものではありません。mpuから取得した5桁の生値を角速度に直す値としてデータシートに記載してあります

Comment: 検索して見つかる記事通りのことをやって再現するか試してみては？ ハードウェアや工作精度の問題かもしれませんし。

Comment: data[8]や0x80以上の値が入っていませんか？data[8] <<8がintで計算されている可能性があり(符号付き)、負数になっているのかもしれません。data[8] <<8をunsigned(uint16_t？)でキャスティングしてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: キャスティングしてみましたが、すると489 +-1.2くらいをウロウロし始めました。

Comment: ネットで見つかる記事は、見つけた限り試しました。それにこのコードも、ある方のコーディングをほぼそのまま真似したものです。しかし、rxは常に-1.5付近をとるとかの記述は見当たらないので質問した次第です

Comment: この辺の記事の補正とか図示とかが参考になるかも。[ESP に６軸センサを i2c 接続する](https://www.ei.tohoku.ac.jp/xkozima/lab/espTutorial2.html), [3 軸加速度・角速度センサ モジュールを使う](http://manabi.science/library/2017/02121501/), [6軸ジャイロ・加速度センサー値をグラフにする](https://www.blog.danishi.net/2020/04/23/post-3454/)

Comment: 解決しました！ループ系での処理がうまくいってませんでした。サンプリング周期をシリアル通信が間に合う速度にまで大きくすることで解決しました。みなさんありがとうございます。